# PHP server ping seeming to cause 502 error

Tags: php, mysql, ping, minecraft

I setup a cron jon to go through my database, grab the ip and port of the Minecraft server via  a whole loop and then ping it to get how many are online, this then stores into the database.

Except I'm thinking there is a server that might be offline so the script hangs when it gets to it I think. My question is how can this be prevented and stop the 502 error that occurs;

**502 Bad Gateway
The server returned an invalid or incomplete response.**

status.class.php { https://github.com/FunnyItsElmo/PHP-Minecraft-Server-Status-Query/blob/master/MinecraftServerStatus/status.class.php }

My Script:

```
<?php
require('../config.php');
require ('../lib/status.class.php');

$SQL = mysql_query("SELECT id, ip, port FROM servers");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($SQL)){
//Fetch the server info
$id     = $row['id'];
$ip     = $row['ip'];
$port   = $row['port'];
echo $id.' - '.$ip.' - '.$port;

$PSQL = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM server_ping WHERE server_id = '$id' AND pinged >= now() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE");
$Pnum = mysql_num_rows($PSQL);

if($Pnum == 0){
    //If the server was not pinged within the last 5 minutes
    //Ping the server
    $status = new MinecraftServerStatus();
    $response = $status->getStatus($ip, $port);
    if($response) {
        $current    = $response['players'];
        $max        = $response['maxplayers'];
    } else {
        $current    = '--';
        $max        = '--';
    }

    //Check if the server is in the list
    $BSQL = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM server_ping WHERE server_id = '$id'");
    $Bnum = mysql_num_rows($BSQL);
    if($Bnum == 0){
        //If the server has never been added - add it
        $ASQL = mysql_query("INSERT INTO server_ping (server_id, current, max) 
            VALUES ('$id', '$current', '$max')");

    } else {
        //If the server has been added - update it
        $ASQL = mysql_query("UPDATE server_ping SET current = '$current', max = '$max' WHERE server_id = '$id'");
    }

} else {
    //If the server was pinged within the last 5 minutes
}
}
?>
```

EDIT:
Intrestingly I did a little troubleshooting by setting the $current = 99 and ran the script it set all the servers to 99 / blah blah. But the page still returned a 502 after...?

Answer (score 0):

To fully analyze your issue, you will need a tool like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark and follow why the 502 happens.

This script already contains an 'offline detection'. I don't think its an issue with offline/online.

Comment: I am using a host to host my site so I wouldn't be able to install anything. If it helps I should mentions there is the server id 7 which pings when the script runs but the later servers don't not sure where it stops.

Comment: Intrestingly I did a little troubleshooting by setting the $current = 99 and ran the script it set all the servers to 99 / blah blah. But the page still returned a 502 after...?

Comment: @Phyore as long as i don't know whats in your database, an server id doesn't help. You should install this script localy and than test it with wireshark

Answer (score 0):

If you are using php-fpm, you could try and restart it.